# Install PHP5 with SQLite3 on Debian Lenny

Tags: php, debian, debian-lenny, sqlite

There is no `apt-get install php5-sqlite3`, as its refereed by **php5-sqlite**

thus, i did:

`apt-get install sqlite3`
and then
`apt-get install php5-sqlite`

Restarted apache2.

When I run `echo sqlite_libversion();` it returns 2.8.17.

I tried `print_r(SQLite3::version());` and it gives an error: **Class 'SQLite3' not found**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Sqlite3](http://www.php.net/manual/en/sqlite3.installation.php) comes as part of PHP 5.3.x.  The packaged Debian version of of PHP5 in Debian Lenny is based on 5.2.6.

From a quick google search I don't see a way to backport this.  To access sqlite3 functionality on 5.2.6 you can use [PDO](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-sqlite.php).  If that is not acceptable, then you probably will need to find/use/build a backport of PHP.

Comment: http://packages.debian.org/squeeze/php5 suggests the version in Debian Squeeze is new enough to have SQLite3 embedded, so you could backport that package. Bear in mind that you'll have to backport security updates by hand until Squeeze releases though.